# Predefined macros and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

As far as I know predefined macros and operations like #ifdef, #define...etc are some thing related to the compiler not to the language standards.

My questions are:

1. Is the above true? completely true? and exceptions?
2. Is the following code completely C++11 valid, standard and best practice?

   ```
   //Some includes here

   #define CONCURRENCY

   int main(){
       //some code here
       #ifdef CONCURRENCY
           concurrency::parallel_for_each(begin(solutions), end(solutions), [&](schedule_& solution){
       #else 
           for (auto& solution:solutions){
       #endif
           //Some code here
       #ifdef CONCURRENCY
           });
       #else
           }
       #endif
   }
   ```

**EDIT**:
a bit out of the scope of the question:

Is the above code the best way to give an option to compile the code with and without concurrency option ?

Comment: I could not format the code,, may someone help me please?

Comment: Indent by 4 spaces minimum and have at least one blank line between code and non-code to get code to format.

Comment: @MicroVirus,@πάντα ῥεῖ Thanks

Comment: The preprocessor is part of the language, and specified in the C++ specification.

Comment: @MicroVirus It's a bit different for numbered list items, one needs another four spaces.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks, I never tried that. I until now always had a blank line before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct. (As far as the macro use is concerned, I didn't really "parse" the code itself.)

C preprocessor directives -- oversimplified, "the stuff that starts with `#something`" -- are handled *before* the compiler actually gets to "see" the code. (They are still part of the language standard, i.e. defined in the same paper as the language.)

As long as whatever you do with the C preprocessor *results* in valid code, the compiler will accept it.

There are things that *do* affect the compiler. `#pragma`, for example, introduces *implementation-defined* functionality. This is covered by the language standard as well.

---

As for "best practice", `#ifdef` / `#else` / `#endif` isn't the cleanest design, but sometimes it's the quickest way to solve platform specifics. As with basically everything in C/C++ (like the dreaded macros), **it's OK as long as you don't overdo it**. Put it in some central place (as opposed to having it spread all over your code base), and document it so that people that come after you can make sense of your `#ifdef`'s, and perhaps replace them with a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, I know that compiler see what is active (even error will not be seen in the non active part. However, other programmers will see them. because of this, I am asking about the best practice that all other programs seeing my code will be comfortable with it

Answer (score 2):

1. The following preprocessor directives

   - `#include`
   - `#define`
   - `#undef`
   - `#if`
   - `#ifdef`
   - `#ifndef`
   - `#error`

   have a standard behavior in C/C++.

   The `#pragma` directive is like an exception because is make to be interpreted by compiler or other external stuff.
2. Your code is valid and standard in C++11, but not follow the best practices. Using preprocessor directives are not encouraged. Current efforts on the developing of C++ language aims to eliminate the need of preprocessor completely. Instead you may use other static code generation techniques like template metaprogramming.